# Hosting the Wcf service on the remote server with the mysql database and consume it in Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am having the Wcf service working with the web source properly. But when i host it on IIS with my system i am unable to fetch the service response from my android.

My source code of wcf service is developed in the different system i have copied the published zip file to my IIS server which is an android development system. I want to consume it in my android application. When there would be a simple response of string from method it will return me the response..

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

request.addProperty("strHello", "abc");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                        URL);

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                        .getResponse();
hideProgressDialog();
```

I have the 2 methods  which returns me the response of string one from simple string and one from the database.

I got the response of the method from the service with the simple string but can't be able to get the response of the method which is connecting to the database of my system's database.

I have changed the web.config file and set the database username and ip to mine one. but not getting the response. please help me as soon as possible how to get the response from service?

Comment: Are you sure that your service is reading the data from the database? There could be a connectivity issue between the service and database or even an issue in the SQL statement that is being run against the database.

Comment: Is there any easy way to test the services database connectivity on my local machine IIS side? 

Currently our wcf services is working fine with ASP.Net MVC web application. But when we are hosting the same services on IIS and trying to access it on android plateform. We are not getting any response. can you please suggest some help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the system and publish the webservice from the developer's system itself and called the webservice from my android code and i got the response. Again after publishing the webservice on developer's system it is not get called from my system but after searching on internet get the solution that there was a problem of firewall.

Thanks  Derek W for helping  me out.